# Changing environment variables from SAS

Tags: linux, oracle, encoding, sas, nls-lang

when I connect to an Oracle database, some symbols are not 
displayed properly. In Oracle I would change the nls_language parameter for 
the session using: 
`alter session set nls_language` and `alter session set nls_territory` 
But how can I change NLS_LANG and NLS_CHARACTERSET in SAS? I do not want to change the 
initora-parameters, the changes should be done only for my session.

Comment: How do you connect to Oracle database? `LIBNAME` statment or library defined by administrator?

Comment: Probably you should set an environment variable `NLS_LANG` for Oracle Client: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html

Comment: I have a libname statement

Comment: Are you launching SAS yourself? Or are you connecting to an application server using Enterprise Guide, SAS/Studio or other tools?  If you are launching it yourself, either on Linux or Windows, then you will have more control.  But even then your system administrator might have hard coded NLS_LANG settings into command that launches SAS.

Comment: I am connecting to the server using SAS Enterprise Guide. Now I try to edit my libname statement.

Comment: I try to use DBCONINIT= option for this, but "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CHARACTERSET" does not work.

Comment: Now I get an error "ORA-29275: partial multibyte character" while I am running a query to the Oracle table from SAS EG. I think its because of difference between NLS_LANG variables.

Comment: What language is your SAS session running in?

Comment: I have this options: LOCALE=EN_US ENCODING=WCYRILLIC